# How to get specific text from webpage into google sheet?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

The issue is I am using the below mentioned function like =(IMPORTHTML(webpage, "table", 2)) but do not get any values.
I have tried this the importfeed, importhtml, importXml functions with similar results. Seems like an authorization request needs to be send if I want to get this data. However, i do not want to go through that process. 
Can somebody please suggest the better/efficient way to figure this out?

Thanks,
Siya

Answer (score 0):

For data needed authentication, u have no way to use importXXXX but app scripts, alternative u have to call up their API.

No luck as I was looking for something similar

Comment: Thank you Weilies for your feedback! I am not a programmer and new to Google sheets not sure how to use app script. Can you please share what you did to make it work.  Many thanks, SiyaK